# How can I jump to a definition without being queried in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, tags, elisp, etags

I have a problem when using [Etags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags#Etags) in Emacs. Everytime I tap \M+. to jump to a difinition point, a query is always popping up, like:

> Find tag (default function_name):

And I have to tap 'Enter' to make sure of it.

But in most cases, I find I can choose the default one. So is there any method with which I can surpress this message?
I found the reason is because:

`(defun find-tag (tagname &optional next-p regexp-p)
  (interactive (find-tag-interactive "Find tag: "))
  ...
  )`

Why do I have to choose a tag? Why can not the default one just be the word under the point? Can I just remove this line? (**interactive**), or is there a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

Going shortly through a couple of defuns in the etags sources via Emacs's awesome `C-h f`, one can find that the default tag to search is determined via a function named `find-tag-default`.

This means you could just define the following function:

```
(defun find-tag-under-point ()
  (interactive)
  (find-tag (find-tag-default)))
```

Then you can bind this to whatever key you want via `define-key` or `global-set-key` or `local-set-key`.

(The `interactive` form is always necessary if you want a function to be a "command" which can be called with `M-x` or bound to a key.)

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's the same solution as the other answer (and I posted it before), with less code, and I tested to make sure it works.

Answer (score -1):

You can write your own functionality over the `find-tag` (or any interactive function likewise)

```
(defun find-tag-under-point (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (cond ((eq arg 9)
     (let ((current-prefix-arg nil))
       (call-interactively 'find-tag)))
    (arg
     (call-interactively 'find-tag))
    (t
     (find-tag (find-tag-default)))))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-.") 'find-tag-under-point)
```

Then hotkey <kbd>C-9</kbd><kbd>M-.</kbd> calls `find-tag` (old function) as usual, but the behaviour of `find-tag-under-point` (new-function) by default is what you want.

Comment: Thank you! But is there some reason that emacs has to issue a query? Can it just pick the default tag?

Comment: It`s unlikely. You have to use another named function instead of `find-tag` or maybe anonymous function `(global-set-key (kbd "M-.") (lambda () (interactive) (find-tag (find-tag-default))))`

Comment: My answer does essentially the same thing but without a query and just picking the default, apparently EXACTLY what @ruanhao wants. I don't know why my answer was downvoted.